# Manipulate not accepting default values

Tags: manipulate

I have pasted my *Mathematica* code below. For some reason, the default value for h, or Δx, while set to 4.5 in the code, keeps displaying at -4 instead.  I have been over and over this example, and I don't understand why this is happening.  If someone would be willing to help me to understand what is going on here and how to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

```
Manipulate[
  f[x_] = 2.195^x - 1;
  Grid[{
    {Row[{Style[
       Text["  approximation of the derivative f'(x) :  " <> 
         ToString[(f[a + h] - f[a])/h]], Green, 15]}]},
    {Row[{Style[
       Text["  derivative: f'(x) \[TildeTilde] " <> 
         ToString[D[f[x], x] /. x -> a]], Red, 15]}]},
    {Plot[{f[x], 
        f[a] + (D[f[t], t] /. t -> a)*(x - a), 
        f[a] + ((f[a + h] - f[a])/h)*(x - a)}, 
     {x, -0.5, 6.5}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green},
     PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 6.25}, {-50, 130}}, Axes -> True, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, -50}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"time (sec)", "distance (ft)"},
     ImageSize -> 450,
     Prolog -> {
       {Line[{{a + h, f[a + h]}, {a, f[a + h]}}]},
       {Line[{{a, f[a + h]}, {a, f[a]}}]}, 
       {PointSize[.02], Blue, Point[{a, f[a]}]},
       {Blue, Text["(x,f(x))", {a + .3, f[a] - 5}]}, 
       {Text["Δx", {a + h/2, f[a + h] - 5}]}, 
       {Text["f(x+Δx) - f(x)", {a + .6, f[a] - (f[a] - f[a + h])/2}]}, 
       {PointSize[.02], Green, Point[{a + h, f[a + h]}]}, 
       {Green, Text["(x+Δx,f(x+Δx))", {a + h - .4, f[a + h] + 7}]}}]}}], 
  {{a, 1, "x"}, 0, 6},
  {{h, 4.5, "Δx"}, -a, 6 - a},
  TrackedSymbols -> {a, a + h},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Where is the definition of h and delta x?

Comment: Why track `{a, a + h}` and not `{a, h}`? The former causes infinite re-evaluation (notice flashing cell bracket).

Comment: Did you clear all variables `a` and `h` before the `Manipulate`? Did you tested it with a fresh kernel? Your problem is not reproducible, I got `h = 4.5`, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with `SaveDefinitions->True`. Change this to `SaveDefinitions->False`, save, and then run... it will probably be OK. Then add `SaveDefinitions->True` back at the end. This should always be the very last thing you do. (In other words, the problem is that an old definition is conflicting with the new one. Enabling `SaveDefinitions` at the end will fix this)

Also, you should probably move the function definition outside the manipulate (and add the colon to use SetDelayed instead of Set):

```
 f[x_] := 2.195^x - 1;
 Manipulate[ ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks, bill s - this seems to have solved my problem!  And István, thanks for pointing out the a+h - this got copied from somewhere else, and I hadn't noticed...